# Imprimir datos especificos con python desde un Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un duda desde hace algunas semanas, no he podido solucionarlo, tengo un archivo json y quiero imprimir y guardar datos especificos.

archivo python:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for client in data['clients']:
        print('First name:', client['first_name']=='David')
        print('Last name:', client['last_name']=='Vega')
        print('Age:', client['age']=='27')
        print('Amount:', client['amount']==7.17)
        print('')
```

archivo json:

```
{
  "clients":[
    {
      "first_name": "David",
      "last_name": "Vega",
      "age": 27,
      "amount": 7.17
    },
    {
      "first_name": "Carlos",
      "last_name": "Torres",
      "age": 28,
      "amount": 8.18
    }
  ]
}
```

quiero que solo me imprima los datos del cliente David, con este codigo el resultado es el siguiente:

```
First name: True
Last name: True
Age: False
Amount: True

First name: False
Last name: False
Age: False
Amount: False
```

y quiero que sea:

```
First name: David
Last name: Vega
Age: 27
Amount: 7.17
```

que no me muestre y guarde los otros datos, agradezco su ayuda si tienen la solucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro, es que cuando ejecuta una instrucción como esta:

```
        print('First name:', client['first_name']=='David')
```

lo que imprimirá será el resultado de la comparación `client['first_name']=='David'`, que será `True` cuando estás en el  `client` apropiado y `False` cuando no.

Lo que quieres hacer es una condición (un `if`) de modo que imprima los datos del cliente **solo si** la condición es cierta.

Habría que modificar tu código así:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for client in data['clients']:
        if client['first_name'] == 'David':
            print('First name:', client['first_name'])
            print('Last name:', client['last_name'])
            print('Age:', client['age'])
            print('Amount:', client['amount'])
            print('')
```

He modificado el resto de los print porque tampoco quieres mostrar `True` si esas comparaciones que hacías eran ciertas. Quieres mostrar los valores de los campos.

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias, saludos desde Colombia

Comment: una pregunta mas si quisiera guardar ese resultado solo tendria que guardar en variables lo que estoy pidiendo? por ejemplo: name = ('First name:', client['first_name']) y luego f.write(name) o como me sugeririas que los guarde? gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres es tener en un fichero exactamente lo mismo que estás viendo en pantalla, puedes ir creando cadenas usando format, por ejemplo: `f.write("First name: {}".format(client['first_name']))`, etc. Pero realmente depende de qué formato quieras tú para el fichero. Tambíen podrías guardar como JSON ese subdiccionario, haciendo simplemente `f.write(json.dumps(client))`.

Comment: el formato no interesa, estaría bien en json para continuar con los mimos formatos. bueno esto es un gran avance para mi, voy a intentar y leer un poco mas de como guardar estos datos, muchas gracias